# What is the best way to have a shape below the main content?

Tags: css, background-image, css-shapes

I have a responsive design like on the following images 
[image]

What is the best way to replicate this shape on the left ? sould i use `img` ? or should i put it as `background images` ? or use it as a css shape ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use linear gradients

```css
.box{
width:200px;
height:350px;
background:white;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(125deg, red 30%, white 30%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(125deg, red 30%, white 30%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(125deg, red 30%, white 30%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(125deg, red 30%, white 30%);
background: linear-gradient(125deg, red 30%, white 30%);
border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Great idea, it works perfectly for me.